# Using IQ on R6S

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I wonder how to use IQ in order to be a good player. I would like to know which loadout and play style should be used with her. For now, it looks like an underpowered character, but I discovered ways to use other under rated characters in a very competitive way so I guess she can also be a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So IQ has a very unique ability for an Assault class op. She can electronically see bombs, cameras, and other electronic things within the environment. That being said, that's how you use IQ. Use IQ to quickly scan the coming rooms, floors, and ceilings for any immediate hits, quickly moving with the assault, or as your own reconnaissance. As the match progresses, it'll be less and less effective, as most equipment has been tripped, destroyed, or non-impact. I've had success in TH with IQ, but in MP, you're not going to need it too much. IQ, for me, became another gun in the fight. Just my $0.02.

Comment: IQ's special scanner is also able to detect the objective bombs through walls so if the opponents have jammed all entrances for drones, you can still pick it up using her scanner to get a more precise location.